# Refactoring two very similar overloads

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have an overload:

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (var odbcConnection = _connection)
            {
                using (var odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    odbcCommand.CommandText = storedProcedure;
                    odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(odbcCommand))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

and another overload:

```
    public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure, List<StoredProcedureParameters> storedProcedureParameters)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var odbcConnection = _connection)
        {
            using (var odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                odbcCommand.CommandText = storedProcedure;

                foreach (var parameter in storedProcedureParameters)
                {
                    odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, 
                        parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
                }

                odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(odbcCommand))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Whose contents are very similar. So similar in fact, the only difference is this line here:

```
foreach (var parameter in storedProcedureParameters)
                    {
                        odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, 
                            parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
                    }
```

I have spent a few hours trying to refactor this guy because they are so similar. I have tried delegates, but it made the code more unreadable. I cannot combine the functionality of the two overloads because the other overloads logic occurs in the middle of the other. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to refactor this into one readable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you could do:

You could always just use the one method, but with an optional `List<StoredProcedureParameters>`.

Like this: *(I've renamed it to `spParams` for brevity)*

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure,
                                        List<StoredProcedureParameters> spParams
                                                     = new List<StoredProcedureParameters>())
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var odbcConnection = _connection)
    {
        using (var odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            odbcCommand.CommandText = storedProcedure;

            foreach (var parameter in spParams)
            {
                odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, 
                    parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
            }

            odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(odbcCommand))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

This way, you can call the same method, and choose whether to pass in the `List<StoredProcedureParameters>` (or not).

Using the parameter with default value of `spParams= new List<StoredProcedureParameters>()` will mean that any existing code calling the original 1 parameter signature will still work, saving time on extra refactoring.

Plus, it means your existing `foreach` block will just iterate over an empty list.

**OR**

You could do similar as the above, just have the `spParams` value be `null` as default, and then do a null check, like this:

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure,
                                        List<StoredProcedureParameters> spParams = null)
{
    //...

    if (spParams != null) // Check if the spParams is null
    {
        foreach(var param in spParams)
        {
            // Loop in here, if not null
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches -

1. You can have the first method pass in an empty list of parameters to the second method:

   ```
   public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure)
   {
       return ExecuteStoredProcedure(storedProcedure, new List<StoredProcedureParameters>());
   }
   ```
2. You can pass null from the first method and add a null check in the second method, like this:

   ```
   public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure)
   {
       return ExecuteStoredProcedure(storedProcedure, null);
   }
   ```

   ...

   ```
   if (storedProcedureParameters != null)
   {
           foreach (var parameter in storedProcedureParameters)
           {
                   odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
           }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag to mark if you want to run the foreach or not. Of course there will be necessary to change the parameter name, and this is only one possible variant of refactor:

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure, List<StoredProcedureParameters> storedProcedureParameters, bool withForEach)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var odbcConnection = _connection)
        {
            using (var odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                odbcCommand.CommandText = storedProcedure;
                if(withForEach)
                foreach (var parameter in storedProcedureParameters)
                {
                    odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, 
                        parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
                }

                odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(odbcCommand))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why could you not do something like this...

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure)
{
    return ExecuteStoredProcedure(storedProcedure, null);
}

public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure, List<StoredProcedureParameters> storedProcedureParameters)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var odbcConnection = _connection)
    {
        using (var odbcCommand = odbcConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            odbcCommand.CommandText = storedProcedure;

            if(storedProcedureParameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in storedProcedureParameters)
                {
                    odbcCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + parameter.ParameterName, parameter.ParameterType, 
                        parameter.LengthOfParameter).Value = parameter.ParameterName;
                }
            }

            odbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(odbcCommand))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```